# pf not execute udp port specific block rule

Tags: freebsd, pfsense, pf

The traffic I want to block can be sniffed as below with tcpdump:

```
19:16:22.391164 IP 95.95.95.95.2036 > 10.10.10.10.443: UDP, length 8192
```

So I wanted to write a rule block any udp destination port 443 traffic.

```
block drop quick on igb3 inet proto udp to any port 443
```

Traffic does not match and does not blocked.

However, It matches and blocks if I write rule as below:

```
block drop quick on igb3 inet proto udp to 10.10.10.10
```

Do you have any remarks?

I am using pf in Freebsd.

Answer (score 0):

Try: `block drop quick on igb3 inet proto udp from any to any port 443`